# jquery ajax sends one 2 json and params post request at the same time

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I'm building a register.
The bottom "Create account":

```
<input type="submit" onclick="sendObj();" value="Create"/>
```

i wanna send json data to the server and the source for sendObj():

```
function sendObj() {

var user = new Object();

user.firstName = $('#firstName').val();
user.lastName = $('#lastName').val();
user.username = $('#username').val();
user.password = $('#password').val();
user.password1 = $('#password1').val();
user.phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
user.email = $('#email').val();

$.ajax(
    {
        url: "signup",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        // mimeType: 'application/json',

        success: function (message)
        {
        }
    }
);
return false;
}
```

but when i submit, there are 2 POST requests send at the .

one XHR post request with json:

```
{"firstName":"vuong","lastName":"le","username":"vking34","password":"bla","password1":"bla","phoneNumber":"01662228388","email":"vking3416@mgial.com"}
```

and one normal post request with params:

```
firstName=vuong&lastName=le&username=vking34&password=bla&password1=bla&phoneNumber=01662228388&email=vking3416%40mgial.com
```

so on the server side, im using jackson to parse the json string. but in the second request, there is surely an Unrecognized token.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token...
```

then servlet immediately send back the response (code status: 500) to the client.

I'm wonder why ajax sends 2 different POST request almost at the same time.
please tell me how to fix it.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `click` event on the button also causes the parent `form` element to submit.

To fix this, instead attach the event handler to the `form` element and use `preventDefault()` to stop the standard submission. Something like this:

```html
<form id="your-form" method="post" action="/foo">
  <!-- your form fields here... -->
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#your-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "signup",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
        lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        password1: $('#password1').val(),
        phoneNumber: $('#phoneNumber').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(message) {
        console.og(message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Note the use of unobtrusive event handlers here, which should always be used in place of the outdated `on*` event attributes placed directly in the HTML.

Comment: very appreciate for your answer.

Comment: i found another solution. i replaced <input type="submit" ... with <button type="button"... once again thanks for your help.